# Proper spelling of "beisbol"

Tags: diferencias-regionales, ortografía, deportes

I had the privilege of attending the [2011 Panamerican Games](http://www.guadalajara2011.org.mx/) last month, and went to the brand new baseball stadium in [Lagos de Moreno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagos_de_Moreno).  The stadium said in big letters:

**Estadio de Beisbol**

[image]

My understanding is that the correct spelling is *béisbol*.

I know it's common for accent marks to be left out in casual writing, or in all-caps, but this is neither casual, nor all-caps.

Is *beisbol* a legitimate alternate spelling (and pronunciation) of the word?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both forms are accepted; which is the more usual depends on what country you're from:

> ### [béisbol o beisbol](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=hinjKayCrD61HGssbs)
>
> ‘Deporte en el que los jugadores han de recorrer ciertos puestos o bases de un circuito, en combinación con el lanzamiento de una pelota desde el centro de dicho circuito’.
>
> La voz inglesa *baseball* se ha adaptado al español con dos acentuaciones, ambas válidas. **La forma *béisbol*,** que conserva la acentuación llana etimológica, **es la usada en España y gran parte de América**, mientras que en países como **México, Guatemala, Colombia, Venezuela, Cuba y la República Dominicana se prefiere la forma aguda *beisbol*** [beisból]. Existe también el calco pelota base, que en varios países de América, especialmente en el área caribeña, se usa reducido a pelota:
>
> > *«Desistió de sus deseos de actuar en la pelota venezolana»* (Nacional [Ven.] 5.10.00).

According to the [*DLE*](http://dle.rae.es/?w=b%C3%A9isbol), the form *beisbol* is used in the following (slightly different) list of countries:

> Tb. **beisbol**, *Antillas, Costa Rica, EE. UU., Guatemala, Honduras, México, Nicaragua, Panamá* y *Venezuela*

---

It's a similar case for other English sport name loans:

| English stress | Nativised stress |
| --- | --- |
| *fútbol* | *futbol* ([*DPD* entry](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=futbol)) |
| *vóleibol* | [*voleibol*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c1LUQk5) (Chile, Méx., Perú y Ur.) ([*DPD* entry](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=1iqOOGVeZD65Py3o1F)) |
| *ráquetbol* | [*raquetbol*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VA6QSON) (Bol., Chile y C. Rica.) |
| *básquetbol* | [*basquetbol*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5ArAgtq) ([*baloncesto*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4ufsnAa)) ([*DPD* entry](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=QwSxCzX54D6NkGn1Ab)) |

Answer (score 6):

The proper spelling is `Béisbol`:

> [Diccionario de la lengua española.](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=b%C3%A9isbol)

It's accented because is a `palabra grave`, that is to say, its stress is on the second syllable from right to left.

I've also seen the original word `baseball` written in spanish texts, but it should be considered an `anglicismo`. The same happens with `football` and `handball`.

---

Interesting enough, in the [comparison between `beisbol` and `baseball` made with googleTrends](http://www.google.com/trends?q=baseball%2C+beisbol&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=1)  you can see that in Spanish, the original English form is also used, but one third as often as the "Spanish" one.

Comment: And adding *béisbol* to the Google trends report shows that form is barely used at all. Although it's unclear that google plays niceley with the *é* - you can't rank by that form, for instance.

Comment: Quick comment. Never seen _handball_ used in Spain, quite likely because, unlike _fútbol_ or _béisbol_ that are pronounced the same way, we use _balonmano_ for handball.

Comment: +1 I agree, the proper spelling is `béisbol` (check RAE) but as shown on the Oxford's Spanish Dictionary link on Richard's answer, in Mexico, both forms are accepted. My guess is that it has to do with the Mexican accent: They pronounce `béisbol` as `beisbol`.

Comment: Mexico has the most Spanish speakers so they don't always do what the minority rule of the RAE tells them to do. It's pretty well-known that there are two Spanish variants for "football": fútbol and futbol, and in that case [the RAE does accept both](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=futbol). The variation with "baseball" is obviously identical. How can a "proper" pronunciation of a loanword from English be dictated anyway. I'm sure the RAE will be edited to describe the actual situation as soon as they feel English borrowings for American sports are important enough.

Comment: This might be an update to the RAE's entry since this answer was posted, but the linked definition explicitly says both forms are accepted, and lists the countries where the aguda form is used: `Tb. beisbol, Ant., C. Rica, EE. UU., Guat., Hond., Méx., Nic., Pan. y Ven.`

Answer (score 5):

It's spelled both ways, but primarily uses the accent.

The [Oxford Spanish dictionary](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=beisbol) supports this.
[Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beisbol) also mentions both spellings.

It's also called pelota base.