# "Guion" vs "Guión" - Are there other words which could be written in multiple ways?

Tags: ortografía, dle, diacríticos

My dictionary uses **guión** while [Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guion_ortogr%C3%A1fico) writes **guion**.

I tried [Google ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=guion,gui%C3%B3n&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=10&smoothing=1) and was nearly convinced that Wikipedia was wrong because nobody else seems to use that spelling today.

I was really surprised to learn from [Real Academia Española](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltConsulta?lema=gui%F3n) that both spellings are correct.

Are there other words which could similarly be written in multiple ways with and without accent marks and the same meaning?

Comment: In the English Wiktionary our term "alternative spellings" covers this and is different to homonyms or synonyms or senses.

Comment: Actually there are pretty interesting cases as: Murciélago and Murciégalo (bat)

Comment: @RandolfRincón-Fadul: yes, there are really interesting cases of "alternative spellings", but the last sentence in the question restricted the situation here to "with and without accent marks". Without that restriction the answers could have included other "bizarre" cases.

Comment: Related: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/242/12

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there are other pairs of words which can be written with and without accent marks; for example (definitions taken from the DRAE):

- omóplato u omoplato. (Del lat. omoplăte, y este del gr. ὠμοπλάτη).

  > 1. m. Anat. Cada uno de los dos huesos anchos, casi planos, situados a uno y otro lado de la espalda, donde se articulan los húmeros y las
  >      clavículas.
- período o periodo. (Del lat. periŏdus, y este del gr. περίοδος).

  > 1. m. Tiempo que algo tarda en volver al estado o posición que tenía al principio.
  > 2. m. Espacio de tiempo que incluye toda la duración de algo.
  > 3. m. Menstruo de las mujeres y de las hembras de ciertos animales.
  > 4. m. Cronol. Ciclo de tiempo. Período juliano, de Metón.
  > 5. m. Fís. Tiempo que tarda un fenómeno periódico en recorrer todas sus fases, como el que emplea un péndulo en su movimiento de vaivén,> la Tierra en su movimiento alrededor del Sol, etc.
  > 6. m. Gram. Conjunto de oraciones que, enlazadas unas con otras gramaticalmente, adquieren sentido completo. U. más refiriéndose a las
  >      construcciones condicionales, concesivas o semejantes.
  > 7. m. Mat. Cifra o grupo de cifras que se repiten indefinidamente, después del cociente entero, en las divisiones inexactas.
  > 8. m. Med. Tiempo que duran ciertos fenómenos que se observan en el curso de las enfermedades.
- icono o ícono.
  (Del fr. icône, este del ruso ikona, y este del gr. bizant. εἰκών, -όνος).

  > 1. m. Representación religiosa de pincel o relieve, usada en las iglesias cristianas orientales.
  > 2. m. Tabla pintada con técnica bizantina.
  > 3. m. Signo que mantiene una relación de semejanza con el objeto representado; p. ej., las señales de cruce, badén o curva en las carreteras.
  > 4. m. Inform. Representación gráfica esquemática utilizada para identificar funciones o programas.
- amoniaco o amoníaco.
  (Del lat. ammoniăcum, y este del gr. ἀμμωνιακόν, de Amón, Júpiter, en Libia).

  > 1. m. Quím. Gas incoloro, de olor irritante, soluble en agua, compuesto de un átomo de nitrógeno y tres de hidrógeno. Es un producto
  >      básico en la industria química. (Fórm. NH3).
  > 2. m. Quím. Disolución acuosa de amoniaco al 35 %, que desprende amoniaco gaseoso.
  > 3. m. Goma resinosa en lágrimas o en masa, compuesta de grumos de color amarillo rojizo por fuera y blanco por dentro, de sabor algo
  >      amargo y nauseabundo y olor desagradable. Se usaba como medicamento
  >      expectorante.
- misil o mísil.
  (Del lat. missĭlis, arrojadizo).

  > 1. m. Proyectil autopropulsado, guiado electrónicamente.
- elegíaco, ca o elegiaco, ca.
  (Del lat. elegiăcus, y este del gr. ἐλεγιακός).

  > 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a la elegía.
  > 2. adj. Lastimero, triste.
- demoníaco, ca o demoniaco, ca.
  (Del lat. daemoniăcus, y este del gr. δαιμονιακός).

  > 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al demonio.
  > 2. adj. endemoniado (‖ poseído). U. t. c. s.
- exegeta o exégeta.
  (Del gr. ἐξηγητής).

  > 1. com. Persona que interpreta o expone un texto.

Well, and having spent some really nice time finding these examples, now I have found this [Lista de palabras con doble acentuación](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Lista_de_palabras_con_doble_acentuaci%C3%B3n) which includes five of the eight examples above and has some more. Well, two of my examples (the pairs *elegíaco-elegiaco* and *demoníaco-demoniaco*) and the last one (suggested by Auron in a comment) are not in that list so my answer at least gives three new examples.

Answer (score 11):

In 2010, RAE made [a number of changes in Spanish spelling](http://www.rae.es/rae/gestores/gespub000018.nsf/%28voAnexos%29/arch8100821B76809110C12571B80038BA4A/%24File/CuestionesparaelFAQdeconsultas.htm#ap0).  One of them was exclusion of the graphical accent in monosyllabic words with diphtongs or triphthongs: *guion, truhan, fie, liais*, etc.

First, RAE introduced strict rules to define what is a **diphtong** for spelling purposes:

- an open vowel (/a/, /e/, /o/) followed or preceded by a closed unstressed vowel  (/i/, /u/): estab-**ai**-s, conf-**ia**-r, d-**ia**-r-**io**, af-**ei**-tar, v-**ie**-nto, p-**ie**, d-**oy** etc (here hyphens do not mean anything at all, I was forced to use them to be able to emphasise word parts).
- two different closed vowels (/i/, /u/): tr-**iu**-nfo, incl-**ui**-do etc.

Similarly, they defined what is a **triphthong** for spelling purposes:

- an open vowel between two closed unstressed vowels: conf-**iái**-s, act-**uái**-s, punt-**uéi**-s, g-**uau**.

As a result, **a number of words that were previously two-syllable words became monosyllabic** for spelling purposes (without any change in pronunciacion) and therefore do not need a graphical accent. These words are:

> Las palabras afectadas por este cambio son formas verbales como
>
> - *crie, crio, criais, crieis* y las de voseo *crias, cria* (de *criar*);
> - *fie, fio, fiais, fieis* y las de voseo *fias, fia* (de *fiar*);
> - *flui, fluis* (de *fluir*);
> - *frio, friais* (de *freír*);
> - *frui, fruis* (de *fruir*);
> - *guie, guio, guiais, guieis* y las de voseo *guias, guia* (de *guiar*);
> - *hui, huis* (de *huir*);
> - *lie, lio, liais, lieis* y las de voseo *lias, lia* (de *liar*);
> - *pie, pio, piais, pieis* y las de voseo *pias, pia* (de *piar*);
> - *rio, riais* (de *reír*);
> - sustantivos como *guion, ion, muon, pion, prion, ruan* y *truhan*;
> - y ciertos nombres propios, como *Ruan* y *Sion*.

--[*Principales novedades de la última edición de la Ortografía de la lengua española (2010)*](http://www.rae.es/rae/gestores/gespub000018.nsf/%28voAnexos%29/arch8100821B76809110C12571B80038BA4A/%24File/CuestionesparaelFAQdeconsultas.htm#ap0)

Comment: But this doesn't answer the original question. The modifications introduced in 2010 that you mentioned don't lead to words with two *accepted* spellings.

Comment: I partly agree on that. However, as far as I understand, _guion_ is now the only accepted spelling. _Diccionario panhispánico de dudas ©2005_ obviously could not include the recent changes introduced in 2010.

Comment: If you define "accepted" as "sanctioned by the RAE", then no. But I think that's a very silly definition of "accepted".

Answer (score 3):

There are many such words in Spanish, they come under a number of different groupings:

- **Change in stress**

  - *período, periodo | gradíolo, gradiolo*
  - *tortícolis, torticolis | barísfera, barisfera*
  - *reúma, reuma*
  - *cantera, cantería | librera, librería | compaña, compañía* `syllabic í`
- **Homophones**

  - **ll / y:** *anafalla, anafaya | jericalla, jericaya* `yeísta`
  - **z / s:** *zuiza, suiza | tenzón, tensón | zandía, sandía* `seseo`
  - **s / c:** *santafecino, santafesino | cebucán, sebucán | fucilazo, fusilazo* `seseo`
  - **z / c:** *zircón, circón | eczema, eccema | zebra, cebra*
  - **g / j:** *girocho, jirocho | gerbo, jerbo | hégira, héjira*
  - **i / y:** *yodo, iodo | tipoy, tipoi | aguay, aguaí | samuray, samurái*
  - **hyphen:** *finoúgrio, fino-ugrio | galaicoportugués, galaico-portugués*
  - **compound:** *no más, nomás | entre tanto, entretanto | de fuera, defuera*
- **Reduced consonant clusters**

  - **Greek initial:** *psicópata, sicópata | mnemónico, nemónico | gnosticismo, nosticismo*
  - **x / s:** *mixtificar, mistificar | excusa, escusa | ambidextro, ambidiestro*
  - **pt / t:** *séptimo, setimo | suscripto, suscrito | concepto, conceto*
  - **sub / su:** *substancia, sustancia | substitución, sustitución*
  - **post / pos:** *postromántico, posromántico | postfijo, posfijo*
  - **trans / tras:**

    - *transcendental, trascendental | demonstración, demostración*
    - *trasmontana, tramontana*
    - *demonstración, demostración | menstruo, mestruo | monstruoso, mostruoso*
- **Consonant changes**

  - **g / c:**

    - *écloga, égloga | secundariamente, segundariamente | renco, rengo*
    - *jiguilete, jiquilete*
    - *tricésimo, trigésimo*
  - **r / l:** *pelegrino, peregrino | quijal, quijar | lilio, lirio*
  - **m / n:** *umjú, unjú | calima, calina | catapum, catapún*
  - **s / j:** *samuga, jamuga | sora, jora | tisera, tijera*
  - **y / j:** *conyugal, conjugal | piyama, pijama*
  - **rr / r:** *corrulla, corulla | sarrapia, sarapia | carrocha, carocha*
  - **-tor:** *novator, novador | percusor, percutor | gladiator, gladiador*
- **Prosthetics**

  - **-s:** *quizá, quizás | pasamano, pasamanos | éxtasi, éxtasis*
  - **a-:** *cumular, acumular | cometedor, acometedor | travesía, atravesía*
  - **-ar / -ear:** *checar, chequear | frutar, frutear | silabar, silabear*
  - **des-, res- / es-:** *estajar, destajar | espumar, despumar | esfriar, resfriar*
- **Loanwords**

  - **etymological/natural stress:** *fútbol, futbol | kárate, karate*
  - **nativised doublets:** *sioux, siux | quasar, cuásar | judo, yudo | xocoyote, socoyote*
  - **tl / cl:** *escuincle, escuintle | achichincle, achichintle, achichinque*
- **[De]palatalisation**

  - **ll / l:** *maullar, maular | rebullicio, rebulicio | tellina, telina*
  - **ll / li:** *buganvilla, buganvilia | enjullo, enjulio*
  - **ñ / n:** *ñublar, nublar | rapiña, rapina | árgueñas | árguenas*
  - **ñ / ni:** *pergeño, pergenio | Antoni<s>o</s> + ito, Antoñito*
- **Vowel shifts**

  - **e / i:** *béstola, bístola | fréjol, fríjol*
  - **o / u:** *troncar, truncar | volcanismo, vulcanismo | sostenido, sustenido*
- **Diphthongs**

  - **e / ie:**

    - *tendente, tendiente | nutrimento, nutrimiento | dezmar, diezmar*
    - *diluente, diluyente | influente, influyente*
  - **o / ue:** *ducho, duecho | viduño, vidueño*
- **Latin doublets:**

  - *bautismo, baptismo | llave, clave | anejar, anexar | fato, hato*
  - *sub iúdice, sub júdice | ipso iure, ipso jure | pro rata, prorrata*
- **Old Spanish:** *cespede, cesped | cibdad, ciudad | troj, trox*
- **sud / sur:** *suroeste, sudoeste | sudafricano, surafricano*
- **metathesis:** *prelado, perlado | cocodrilo, crocodilo*

etc

Answer (score 2):

There are thousands of dictionary lemmas with multiple spellings. By doing some crazy scripting, I've compiled a list of some 4000+. Many times, the distinguishing element is an accent, but most of the time it's a letter insertion, deletion or substitution.

I can't post all of them here without cluttering everything up, but for the sake of completeness, I've compiled the [whole list of dictionary lemmas with multiple spellings](http://dirae.es/static/multigrafias.html) (self-promotion disclaimer: I'm the author of Dirae), admitted by the Diccionario de la Real Academia Española, sorted by frequency of use in the Spanish language (most common words at the top). The heuristics used to produce the list are a bit rough, so there may have slipped in several false positives, and there may be many false negatives missing.

This is a small relevant subset:

- [ablanedo o ablanero](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=ablanedo)
- [achichincle, achichinque o achichintle](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=achichincle)
- [ademprio o ademprío](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=ademprio)
- [aeromancia o aeromancía](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=aeromancia)
- [aerostato o aeróstato](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=aerostato)
- [aeróbic o aerobic](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=aer%C3%B3bic)
- [afrodisíaco, ca o afrodisiaco, ca](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=afrodis%C3%ADaco)
- [agar-agar o agaragar](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=agar-agar)
- [agrafia o agrafía](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=agrafia)
- [aguaucle o aguautle](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=aguaucle)
- [aguazul o aguazur](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=aguazul)
- [alabastrita o alabastrites](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=alabastrita)
- [alacaluf o alacalufe](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=alacaluf)
- [alauda o alaude](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=alauda)
- [alazán, na o alazano, na](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=alaz%C3%A1n)
- [alcací o alcacil](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=alcac%C3%AD)
- [aldeorrio o aldeorro](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=aldeorrio)
- [alectomancia o alectomancía](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=alectomancia)
- [alfoliero o alfolinero](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=alfoliero)
- [aljarfa o aljarfe](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=aljarfa)
- [almarraja o almarraza](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=almarraja)
- [almocárabe o almocarbe](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=almoc%C3%A1rabe)
- [almogavaría o almogavería](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=almogavar%C3%ADa)
- [almoháter o almohatre](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=almoh%C3%A1ter)